# Does a boot loader unmount the ramdisk BEFORE mounting the root file system on the hard drive?

Tags: startup, boot-loader

In a recent online course, a RHEL/CentOS instructor mentioned the following:

> The boot loader then executes the kernel. During the kernel stage, the
>   kernel loads a ramdisk into memory. This ramdisk serves as a temporary
>   root file system. This file system includes kernel modules, drivers,
>   and possibly even kickstart files. **Later, the kernel unmounts the
>   ramdisk and mounts the root file system on the hard drive.** And then,
>   starts the initialization stage by executing the first process. In the
>   initialization stage, the grandfather process runs. In older versions
>   of Red Hat this was the Init process.

That seems backwards to me.  Wouldn't the kernel need SOME filesystem available throughout the entire process?  That highlighted line above suggests that there's a brief moment in time when there's absolutely no filesystem running.

Comment: note the question's phrasing implies any of that is the bootloader's responsibility; this is not correct.  the bootloader is not used after kernel's initialization begins.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a boot loader unmount the ramdisk […] ?

No.

> Later, the kernel unmounts the ramdisk and mounts the root file system on the hard drive. And then, starts the initialization stage by executing the first process.

This is wrong.

The initramfs contains a program named `/init`.  This program is executed, and is the first (user) process *whilst the initramfs is still there*.  Indeed, it is this program that triggers any unmounting that goes on.

[This is the `/init` program used on Debian 9 Linux](https://sources.debian.org/src/initramfs-tools/0.130/init/).  Fedora has [a similar system named Dracut](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Dracut).  As you can see, the script loads modules, runs hooks, mounts the final root filesystem, and finally overlays itself with the `run-init` program that is to be found in the klibc-utils package.  (Earlier versions used either `run-init` or `switch_root` according to what was available.)  [Dracut still uses `switch_root`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/boot/dracut/dracut.git/tree/modules.d/99base/init.sh#n384).  Dracut at this point [has spawned an entire `systemd-udevd` subsystem](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/boot/dracut/dracut.git/tree/modules.d/99base/init.sh#n152) which has run and autodetected devices and run dæmons for and mounted volumes from those devices.  Dæmons spawned by `systemd-udevd` for DASDs continue to run in parallel with `switch_root`.

The `run-init` program [in its turn deletes the contents of the initramfs, `chroot`s itself to the new root filesystem, opens its `/dev/console`, and overlays itself with whatever the `init` program on that filesystem is to be](https://sources.debian.org/src/klibc/2.0.4-10/usr/kinit/run-init/runinitlib.c/#L158), which it knows from either a variable named `init` on the kernel command line or [a default for that variable assumed by the first `/init` program](https://sources.debian.org/src/initramfs-tools/0.130/init/#L52).  `switch_root` does much the same, albeit with some slight differences.  Dracut passes it the name of the `init` program [which it has similarly obtained from the kernel command line](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/boot/dracut/dracut.git/tree/modules.d/99base/init.sh#n280).

As you can see, *neither* the kernel *nor* a boot loader trigger any of this.  The boot loader is well out of the picture by the time that the `/init` program is started as process #1, and the kernel simply does what the `/init` program, the programs in the hooks that it spawns, and the two further programs that it overlays itself with, tell it.

And no, there is *no* point in this process, from the moment that process #1 is started with the `/init` program from the initramfs onwards, where it is possible to have no filesystem mounted.  There is always at least one process running, and that process must have a working directory, a root directory, and a program image file, all of which must reference vnodes from a mounted volume *somewhere*.

You'll observe that the original initramfs can only go away when the last mount point is moved off it and the last process to use it, as per-process current directory, per-process root directory, or program image file, goes away — or, as `run-init` and `switch_root` do, switches both working directory and root directory to some other volume and overlays itself with a program image from a file from some other volume.  Note that the systemd people accommodate the possibility that the initramfs does not in fact go away at all, because there a programs running from images from that volume, and remains present for the lifetime of the system.

So what actually happens is that both the original initramfs and the final root filesystem are *both* present at one point in the process, and indeed possibly from then onwards.  Far from there being a point where there are *zero* root filesystems, there is a point where there are *multiple* root filesystems and then (as the references to the initramfs go away) it drops back down to one again.  (Note that filesystems for `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev`, `/run`, `/dev/shm`, and `/dev/pts` are present at the time of `run-init`/`switch_root` running, so the *total* count of mounted filesystems, root and otherwise, remains well above two throughout the bootstrap process.)

## Further reading

- Harald Hoyer (2013-10). *[dracut](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/dracut/dracut.html)*.  version 3.0.  kernel.org.
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2013).  *[systemd and Storage Daemons for the Root File System](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/RootStorageDaemons/)*.  freedesktop.org.

Comment: +1\* thanks for the specifics.  \* (actual +1s to be provided later by actual fully-signed-in-accounts and such.  (sorry))

Answer (score 1):

A running kernel doesn't **need** a filesystem mounted any more than it needs a configured network interface - unless, of course, it (or some code running under the kernel, such as an `init` process) is actively using them at the time, which is not the case when switching from a temporary rootfs to the real rootfs.

Remember, the kernel doesn't have a mounted filesystem from the time it first starts to the time it mounts the initrd (or the actual rootfs if it's not using an initrd).  This happens some time after initial hardware probing and device and driver initialisation.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not following. If the ram disk stores kernel modules and drivers... and that's gone/unavailable... how is it able to continue mounting the root file system on the hard drive?  Is that prerequisite knowledge stored/available somewhere else?

Comment: the modules are loaded into the kernel. after that, the copies of them on the ramdisk are no longer needed.

Comment: Ah, that's the part I was missing.  Thank you!

Comment: This is wrong.  When switching from the one root filesystem to the other _there is_ a process running, sometimes more than one if `systemd-udevd` is involved in the initramfs, which needs at least one filesystem present (to contain the root and working directory of the processes) and thus undermines this answer completely.